# access npm modules locally in case npm server is down

Tags: npm

I am looking to store npm modules in a cache/locally in case the npm server is down and I cannot access the modules.

I hear npm-cache or npm-offline work well, but I'm not sure if they actually solve the problem I face - which is accessing an npm module locally.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Install `offline-npm` with

```
sudo npm install -g offline-npm
```

`offline-npm` will run a local http server with the content of your cache. Launch the server with:

```
offline-npm -n -d
```

You can then install packages from your cache with:

```
npm --registry http://localhost:4873 install <packagename>
```

To inspect the content of your cache run:

```
npm cache ls
```

You can also add a package to your cache without installing it with:

```
npm cache add <package>
```

For more information, read the [official documentation of offline-npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/offline-npm).